# ElasticSearch, is there performance degradation if writing objects inside other objects?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of objects like

```
{
"type1_a":".... value ....",
"type1_b":".... value ....",
"type1_c":".... value ....",
"type1_d":".... value ....",
"type1_.....":".... value ....",
"type2_a":".... value ....",
"type3_b":".... value ....",
"type4_c":".... value ....",
"type5_d":".... value ....",
"type6_.....":".... value ...."
}
```

but I was thinking about putting the objects as

```
{
    "type1": { 
          "a": ".... value ...."
          "b": ".... value ...."
          "etc..": ".... value ...."
    },
    "type2": { 
          "a": ".... value ...."
          "b": ".... value ...."
          "etc..": ".... value ...."
    }
}
```

I've about a 100 of those attributes, with couple TBs of data (fairly large index).

I was wondering if the elastic search engine in theory treats in a less efficient way what is nested compared to what it is on the first level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely nested data type in Elasticsearch is very costly and you indeed has a really large index. Please read the [very interesting blog of Go-Jek engineering on trouble with nested documents](https://blog.gojekengineering.com/elasticsearch-the-trouble-with-nested-documents-e97b33b46194) and how they optimized it.

In-short, if performance is a critical aspect for you and if you can avoid the nested data-type, then benchmark it in your environment/setup and than only take some final decision.

Comment: The type here is not "nested" as in "a list of searcheable objects", but it would still be a map of maps